# How to make below HTTPs connection over Android secure

Tags: android, http, ssl, https, connection

I have below thing over secure socket layer which creates a tunnel using trust manager, but i don't understand what is impact of ALLOW ALL HOST NAME. Can someone explain?

Can someone suggest what changes i require to make in code?

```
        public class EasySSLSocketFactory implements SocketFactory, LayeredSocketFactory {

            private SSLContext sslcontext = null;

            private SSLContext createEasySSLContext() throws IOException {
                try {
                    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                    context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new EasyX509TrustManager(null) }, null);
                    return context;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            private SSLContext getSSLContext() throws IOException {
                if (this.sslcontext == null) {
                    this.sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();
                }
                return this.sslcontext;
            }

            /**
             * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#connectSocket(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String, int,
             *      java.net.InetAddress, int, org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
             */
            public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock, String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort,
                    HttpParams params) throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
                int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
                int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);
                InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
                SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket) ((sock != null) ? sock : createSocket());

                if ((localAddress != null) || (localPort > 0)) {
                    // we need to bind explicitly
                    if (localPort < 0) {
                        localPort = 0; // indicates "any"
                    }
                    InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);
                    sslsock.bind(isa);
                }

                sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);
                sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
                return sslsock;

            }

            /**
             * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#createSocket()
             */
            public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
                return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket();
            }

            /**
             * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#isSecure(java.net.Socket)
             */
            public boolean isSecure(Socket socket) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                return true;
            }

            /**
             * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory#createSocket(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String, int,
             *      boolean)
             */
            public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException,
                    UnknownHostException {
                return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
            }

            // -------------------------------------------------------------------
            // javadoc in org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory says :
            // Both Object.equals() and Object.hashCode() must be overridden
            // for the correct operation of some connection managers
            // -------------------------------------------------------------------

            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                return ((obj != null) && obj.getClass().equals(EasySSLSocketFactory.class));
            }

            public int hashCode() {
                return EasySSLSocketFactory.class.hashCode();
            }
            }


        public class EasyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

            private X509TrustManager standardTrustManager = null;

            /**
             * Constructor for EasyX509TrustManager.
             */
            public EasyX509TrustManager(KeyStore keystore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
                super();
                TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                factory.init(keystore);
                TrustManager[] trustmanagers = factory.getTrustManagers();
                if (trustmanagers.length == 0) {
                    throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("no trust manager found");
                }
                this.standardTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustmanagers[0];
            }

            /**
             * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[],String authType)
             */
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                standardTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certificates, authType);
            }

            /**
             * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[],String authType)
             */
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                if ((certificates != null) && (certificates.length == 1)) {
                    certificates[0].checkValidity();
                } else {
                    standardTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certificates, authType);
                }
            }

            /**
             * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#getAcceptedIssuers()
             */
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return this.standardTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
            }
            }


        public static HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
            try {
                KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                trustStore.load(null, null);

                SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
                sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

                HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

                SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
                registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

                ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

                return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new DefaultHttpClient();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your problem is `SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER`, you should change it to something more appropiate.

Comment: Any idea what else can i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use of AllowAllHostnameVerifier() or
>   SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER essentially turns off
>   hostname verification when using SSL connections. This is equivalent
>   to trusting all certificates.

So you need to change your hostname verifier:

Options are:

1. `BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier`

   The hostname must match either the first CN, or any of the
   subject-alts. A wildcard can occur in the CN, and in any of the
   subject-alts.

   The only difference between BROWSER_COMPATIBLE and STRICT is that a
   wildcard (such as *.foo.com") with BROWSER_COMPATIBLE matches all
   subdomains, including "a.b.foo.com.
2. `StrictHostnameVerifier`

   The hostname must match either the first
   CN, or any of the subject-alts. A wildcard can occur in the CN, and
   in any of the subject-alts. The one divergence from IE6 is how we
   only check the first CN. IE6 allows a match against any of the CNs
   present. We decided to follow in Sun Java 1.4's footsteps and only
   check the first CN. (If you need to check all the CN's, feel free to
   write your own implementation!).

   A wildcard such as "*.foo.com" matches only subdomains in the same
   level, for example "a.foo.com". It does not match deeper subdomains
   such as "a.b.foo.com".
3. If you want to implement verification not present in one of these you need to create your own hostname verifier.

[Some basic information about Hostname Verification](http://books.google.pl/books?id=OO0HPi3xaBYC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=android%20hostname%20verifier&source=bl&ots=zScl6bzbeC&sig=6GliSimisfCOzEpf5SkAUG8brNo&hl=pl&sa=X&ei=XBLEU7nZOc6v7AbhhoC4DA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwATgU#v=onepage&q=android%20hostname%20verifier&f=false)

Comment: Thankyou @Than that was really really brief and very helpful explanation. I will do the follow changes...Once again thanks a lot :)